# Get checkbox value with php

Tags: php, html

I try to determine if a checkbox is checked or not, but i get an error.

**test.php**

```
<html>
    <body>
        <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">

            Use Proxy : <input type="checkbox" name="use_proxy"><br><br>

            <input type="submit">
        </form>

        <?php 
            $use_proxy  = $_POST['use_proxy'];

            if ($use_proxy != "on")
            {
                $use_proxy = "off";
            }

            echo "<p> use_proxy = " . $use_proxy . "</p><br>"; 
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

I get this error:
Notice: Undefined index: use_proxy in C:\xampp\htdocs\mbcl\checkbox_test.php on line 11
How can i solve it?

Comment: your code seems correct.

Answer (score 3):

This is the behaviour of checkbox until they are checked , they can not be fetched at backend(PHP) . You can try as below-

```
<html>
    <body>
        <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">

            Use Proxy : <input type="checkbox" name="use_proxy" value="off"><br><br>

            <input type="submit">
        </form>

        <?php 
            $use_proxy  = isset($_POST['use_proxy'])?"on":"off";
            echo "<p> use_proxy = " . $use_proxy . "</p><br>"; 
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Obviously because you weren't using ISSET

Comment: @CodeGodie And why is it necessary to use `isset`? The logik looks totaly ok.

Comment: Because ISSET will check if POST actually exists. Initially before you submit your form, There are no POST requests, thus giving you those errors

Comment: @EdwardBlack ,one more thing , what you are getting that is not "error" , they are "warning" in real . You would be overcome this by using "error_reporting(0) " too.

Comment: You should not turn off error reporting. These warning/errors will help you make better code

Comment: @CodeGodie correctly said , but sometimes there are occasion such as ajax call , it helps us..